# pipenv install gives "pew is not in your PATH"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv

I have Mac OS X El Capitan, installed python 3.6, pip, pipenv. Can't make pipenv work:

```
pipenv install
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Warning: it looks like pew is not in your PATH. We cannot continue until this is resolved.
```

I checked pew - it's in the `/Users/kosteg/Library/Python/3.6/bin`

Here is my ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=/Users/kosteg/.local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/Users/kosteg/Library/Python/3.6/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/Users/kosteg/Library/Python/3.6:$PATH
alias python=python3
alias pip=pip3
```

How to fix the path issue?

Comment: I was seeing this error with correct path configuration. Simply running `pipenv --update` solved it for me (updated to 8.3.2).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Uninstall `virtualenv`, `pipenv` and `pew`.

Then, follow this: first install `virtualenv`, then `pew`, then `pipenv` with simple command `pip install`.

Comment: This worked for me on macos using homebrew installed pyton

Comment: Works on Windows, too. It would be nice to have some explanation on why this is happening.

Answer (score 7):

`sudo -H pip3 install pew` fixes the issue

Comment: To install sudo is not a good option, because of security reasons. Furthermore sudo should not be required to make it work.

Comment: Agree, The solution below to uninstall and reinstall in order worked for my homebrew install. Issue was conflict between macos python and homebrew.