# When creating virtualenv on python I have a warning : "it looks like pew is not in your PATH"

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, virtualenv, pipenv

I'm working on Python 3.6.3 on a Windows 10 environment
I executed in that order :

```
py -m pip install virtualenv
py -m pip install pew
py -m pip install pipenv
```

Then :

```
py -m pipenv --three
```

And the result is

```
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe to create virtualenv…
Warning: it looks like pew is not in your PATH. We cannot continue until this is resolved.
```

I tried the solution below but it doesn't work :
[pipenv install gives "pew is not in your PATH"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308150/pipenv-install-gives-pew-is-not-in-your-path)

Comment: I can say only that your package installation order works for me(Windows 10, Python 3.6.3)